# Unity: Have several implementation and decide which one to use

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I have to start soon a WPF application, we decided to go for PRISM + Unity to help us a little bit with the architecture.

I was having a question. We will have a `DataRepository`, which implements an `IDataRepository`.

The thing is that we will after that also have an `OfflineDataRepository` which implement the same interface.

We would like to be able to give some logic on which implementation to return depending on the state of the application(online/offline).

How could I achieve this with Prism+Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [InjectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff661868(v=pandp.30).aspx) to accomplish what you are after.  This will get executed every time an IDataRepository is needing to be instantiated.

```
container.RegisterType<IDataRepository, DataRepository>("Online");
container.RegisterType<IDataRepository, OfflineDataRepository>("Offline");
container.RegisterType<IDataRepository>(new InjectionFactory(c => { 
    var connectivityStatus = /*TODO: logic to determine if online*/
        ? "Online"
        : "Offline";
    return c.Resolve<IDataRepository>(connectivityStatus);            
});
```

Comment: Ok, and this is evaluated which time we ask for an instance?

Comment: Yep, the delegate specified to the constructor of InjectionFactory is run every time an instance is resolved.